# how to show one product pic on page load

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have one table to store product images, and each prod can has more than one pic in image table, to specify which image belongs to which product, i store ProdId of product in image table, It works fine at this point, but when i want to show 1 specific pic(last added one) on lage load event of product page, it shows all pics of the prod, its like all those pics belongs to another prod but those are actually belong to one product, please help me i just wanna show only one pic(last added one) on page load not all of them??

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                FillProds();
            }
        }
 protected void FillProds()
        {
            string _session = Session["lang"].ToString();
            if (_session == "tr-TR")
            {
                var _tblProd = (from x in _db.Tbl_Prods
                                join y in _db.Tbl_Imgs
                                on x.ProdId equals y.ProdId
                                join z in _db.Tbl_Cats
                                on x.CatId equals z.CatId
                                orderby x.DbDate descending
                                select new
                                {
                                    ProdId = x.ProdId,
                                    ProdCode = x.ProdCode,
                                    ProdName = x.ProdNameTr,
                                    ImgUrl = y.ImgUrl,
                                }).ToList();

                lvListAll.DataSource = _tblProd;
                lvListAll.DataBind();
            }
            else if (_session == "ru-RU")
            {
                var _tblProd = (from x in _db.Tbl_Prods
                                join y in _db.Tbl_Imgs
                                on x.ProdId equals y.ProdId
                                join z in _db.Tbl_Cats
                                on x.CatId equals z.CatId
                                orderby x.DbDate descending
                                select new
                                {
                                    ProdId = x.ProdId,
                                    ProdCode = x.ProdCode,
                                    ProdName = x.ProdNameRu,
                                    ImgUrl = y.ImgUrl,
                                }).ToList();

                lvListAll.DataSource = _tblProd;
                lvListAll.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please share your Page_Load().

Comment: Maybe you can use `.Take(1)` on you LINQ calls.

Comment: Create two queries one which will get the latest images and then Join it with the _tblProd.

Comment: I know Take() method but in this query im retriving a list of images:/

Comment: the solution way is to create one more query of course but what are those 2 queries, im askin here to get them:)

Comment: And also i have only one listview, i think its nt possible to link them with two different query with data source??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var images = (from p in _db.Tbl_Prods
              join img in _db.Tbl_Imgs on p.ProdId equals img.ProdId 
              group img by p.ProdId into g
              select new { g.Key, MaxImageId = g.Max(x => x.ImageId) })
              .Select(x => x.MaxImageId).ToArray();

 var prods = (from p in  _db.Tbl_Prods
              join img in _db.Tbl_Imgs on p.ProdId equals img.ProdId 
              where images.Contains(img.ImageId)
              select new 
              { 
                     ProdId = x.ProdId,
                     ProdCode = x.ProdCode,
                     ProdName = x.ProdNameRu,
                     ImgUrl = img.ImgUrl
              });
```

Comment: Good to know it worked. Try this [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) to understand different LINQ examples.